# Постоянный кастомный umask для выбранного пользователя при вызове через sudo

Tags: sudo, permissions

Есть тестовый сервер (Debian 7), на котором мы с друзяшками развлекаемся. Все процессы, которые обычно висят на www-data, разбиты по отдельным пользователям (nginx, php-fpm, thin), у всех сервисов и заинтересованных лиц есть группа webdev, которая, в идеале, должна сохранить данные о создателе файла/папки, предоставляя при этом полный доступ к файлам всем участникам группы. Сохранение группы за всеми файлами внутри `/var/www` реализовано без проблем (`chmod g+s -R`), `umask 002` (пока что) прописан в `/etc/profile`, однако когда требуется выполнить что-нибудь от php-fpm (`sudo -u php-fpm -H`), файлы создаются без доступа от группы на запись (rw-r--r-- вместо rw-rw-r--). Проблема временно решена через хардкод `umask` в файле `sudoers`, но это дикий костыль, который хотелось бы как-то разрешить - либо задать как-то umask только для php-fpm, либо подсказать мне способ использования sudo, при котором будут подтягиваться все `/etc/profile` и прочие файлы. `/etc/pam.d/common-session`, `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` и `/etc/login.defs` патчил, добавляя `pam_umask.so` и `UMASK` - безрезультатно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в каталоге с признаком `sgid` создаётся новый файл, то ему присваивается принадлежность пользователю, который создал его (`php-fpm`) и группе, которой принадлежит сам каталог (`webdev`), но право на запись не наследуется, т.е. в каталоге с правами `drwxrwsr-x www-data webdev` вновь созданные файлы будут иметь разрешение по умолчанию `-rw-r--r-- php-fpm webdev`.
Судя по всему есть три варианта:

- использование umask;
- использование ACL;
- запуск по крону `chmod 644 -R /var/www/`

Сам на данный момент пользуюсь простым вариантом со скриптом в кроне:

`cat /root/faxes.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
find /var/spool/hylafax/recvq/ -name fax*.tif -mmin -1 -exec chmod 750 {} \;
scp -p -i /root/rsync-key `find /var/spool/hylafax/recvq/ -name fax*.tif -mmin -1` 192.168.0.5:/share/faxes/new/
```

Скрипт меняет права для файлов, созданных за последнюю минуту, и копирует их в расшаренную папку.